# How can I replace a string in all filenames in a directory? (specifically I need to remove "\#015" from all file names in a directory

Tags: linux, unix, replace, sed, awk

Many files in a directory (`/root/path/`) have a strange character string appended to them (`\#015`).  Help me replace them with regular names without the strange string.

I need:

```
/root/path/img1.png\#015
/root/path/img2.jpg
/root/path/img3.png\#015
```

To be:

```
/root/path/img1.png
/root/path/img2.jpg
/root/path/img3.png
```

Can you help?

Comment: My issue was resolved by converting end of line (EOL) from Windows to Unix in a `rsync` bash script that was failing - commenting because this answer was first thing that showed up in search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for file in *\#015
do
   mv -- "$file" "${file%\#015}"
done
```

You may need to escape the "\"s. Try it in a tmp directory first.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `rename` installed, this becomes a fairly simple task:

```
rename 's/\\#015$//' /root/path/*\\#015
```

You can add the `-f` flag to force overwriting existing files if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd solved a similar problem in the past with a little shell.

```
cd /root/path/
ls | grep '\#015' | sed 's/\(.*\)\\#015/mv & \1/' | sh
```

Comment: and of course, Ryan, you'd leave off the trailing `| sh`, so you could look at the commands 'that will be executed' until you were certain that those commands will not have unintended consequences, right? ;-)  Good luck to all.

Comment: Instead of `ls | grep '\#015'`, it'd be more natural to use `ls *\#015`. I wouldn't use the approach anyway though since a simple shell loop is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `find` and parameter substitution as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

find -name '*\\#015' | while IFS= read -r f
do
    mv -- "${f}" "${f%?????}"
done
```

- Put the above code in a script called `my_script.sh` in your `/root/path/`, and run it by `chmod +x my_script.sh && ./my_script.sh`
- Note that this will apply the changes recursively to all subfolders under `/root/path/` as well.

**Explanation:**

- `find -name '*\\#015'`: find all files ending with `\#015`
- Then for each such file found: `mv "${f}" "${f%?????}"` renames it from the old name to a new name with the last 5 characters in the file name removed.

Comment: Remember to quote your variables unless you have a very specific reason not to. The above will fail if your file name contains spaces or any globbing characters or start with a - sign.

Comment: @EdMorton Good call. Editing that now.

Comment: Stick a `--` after `mv`. More importantly though, your loop will not work as written. You need to write it as `find -name '*\\#015' | while IFS= read -r file`.

Comment: to clarify, you can't do `for f in $files` or it will fail for file names that contains spaces and do globbing, but neither can you do `for f in "$files"` or all file names will be concatenated into one string. Hence the need for piping the find output to a while read loop. It will still fail for file names that contain newlines, you'd need to use xargs or find -exec to get around that, but it's all getting probably needlessly complicated. `for file in *` is the way to go if possible as it's clear, simple, and foolproof.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for pointing that out. Could you elaborate a bit on `while IFS= read -r file`? I'm assuming that sets the internal field separator to " "? (but isn't IFS space by default?) Also, is there a resource you could point me to for reading up on `read`? I tried looking but results are saturated with the syscall instead.

Comment: It sets IFS to the null string so no field splitting occurs. read -r just tells read to work in raw mode. Between the 2 you get your variable populated with exactly what was input. I'd have expected the man page for your shell would talk about it.

Comment: @sampson-chen, `read` is actually a shell builtin, so `help read` would be of use here.